# How to compare directories from two different location in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I want to compare directory from two different locations. I'm wondering if it's possible to access directory outside my server? Or is there any other way to do the file comparison?

Comment: How far outside your server?  On the same domain?  Any firewalls in between?

Comment: Basically I want to compare my dev server and test server files before submit to main. Asp.net page will be in dev.

Comment: If you use the 'Copy Website' under 'Website' in visual studio it will compare for you and show you which files are different.

Comment: You mean under solution?

Comment: What will you be comparing? What files are present? File sizes? Last Modified dates?

Comment: Yea, basic file info. I just want to check if the file is different from the other.

Answer (score 0):

To access files on another server using standard `System.IO` methods (i.e. not FTP) you need two things:

1. A mechanism set up that will allow you to access that location (simple share, DFS, WebDAV, etc.)
2. Permissions to access the share and the files

From there you access the folders using their UNC path:

```
\\{ServerName}\{ShareName}\folder1\sub1\...
```

Comment: I'm using subversion, do you know if I could use subversion to compare both directory?